# MapBox VectorTile

Tags: mapbox, sharpmap

I'm trying to decode [mapbox vector tiles](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec) for use with SharpMap.

Does a tile know its position in the grid (x, y) and zoom level (z), or do I have to provide these values alongside with the vector tile?

Comment: What exactly is your question? These Vector tiles follow the same XYZ format: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I want to know if the information of the position in the grid (x, y, z) value is encoded in the tile itself or if i have to provide x, y z value to properly decode the tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Version 2.0 of the vector tile specification](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/tree/master/2.0#3-projection-and-bounds%22Version%202.0%20of%20the%20vector%20tile%20specification%22) clearifies this:

> A Vector Tile SHOULD NOT contain information about its bounds and projection. The file format assumes that the decoder knows the bounds and projection of a Vector Tile before decoding it.